# Should [wealth] be a synonym of [net-worth]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I was reviewing some edit suggestions for the wiki of [wealth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) and it basically suggested that it was related to net-worth. There is only one question with this tag. I think we should either make a synonym or agree on a definition for wealth that is distinct from [net-worth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/net-worth).

Comment: No one has any opinion on this one?

Comment: "status completed" makes me feel we should have a drink to celebrate the accomplishment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm inclined to just delete the tag from the one remaining question, it doesn't really add much to it and wouldn't even if replaced with [net-worth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/net-worth). Perhaps we should first import the tag wiki into [net-worth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/net-worth) as that doesn't have one.

EDIT: I've deleted the [wealth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) from its one question and copied its tag wiki to [net-worth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/net-worth). I think [wealth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) will be naturally cleaned up soon, we can see if it reappears organically.

Comment: I agree with this approach.

Comment: Good approach. They're not technically the same any way, IMHO. Wealth would be an abundance, whereas net worth can describe low figures too.